# Post Request not working with React, Redux and Ducks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, httprequest

I'm building an app with React, TS, Redux and Ducks (https://github.com/erikras/ducks-modular-redux)

I have several actions and reducers already built. But I am finding some troubles with the Post actions. I will leave you the code here as an example:

```
export const getChallenges: ReduxActionCreator = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    const data = await ApiClient.get('/challenges');
    console.log('get', data);
    dispatch({
      type: types.GET_CHALLENGES_SUCCESS,
      payload: data.data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

export const postChallenges: ReduxActionCreator = (body) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    const data = await ApiClient.post('/challenges', body);
    console.log('post', data);
    dispatch({
      type: types.ADD_CHALLENGE_SUCCESS,
      payload: data.data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

So, getChallenges is working fine and I already render it in the browser.

For some reason, postChallenges is not even firing in Redux devtools, not even giving me an error.

I'm calling it simply like this:

```
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleSubmitForm = () => {
    dispatch(postChallenges(values));
    push(Path.AddMissions);
  };
```

ApiClient code

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const ApiClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://thnk.gendesa.genit.com.ar/api/v1/',
  timeout: 20 * 1000,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
});

ApiClient.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => response.data,
  (error) => Promise.reject(error),
);
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: is `push(Path.AddMissions);` being called? can you console.log the internals of `handleSubmitForm` and see what is running?

Comment: also, forgive me if i'm wrong, but are you sure you need to do `dispatch(postChallenges(values));` and not just `postChallenges(values)`?

Comment: Could you share you `ApiClient` code?

Comment: @TKoL it is being called successfully. Somehow is posyChallenges is not being called. If I console.log the postChallenges function it appears in the console.

Comment: @TKoL already tried without the dispatch, but has to be there. In the other component that is working it is implemented like that

Comment: @axtck sure! I'll add it to the post

Comment: Just a sidenote: you are writing a very outdated style of Redux here, especially in combination with TypeScript that will make you write 4-5 times the amount of code necessary for modern Redux. I'd recommend following the official Redux tutorial: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts

Comment: @phry thanks for the recommendation, I'll read it. Maybe is because we are using ducks, but ofc if I can do something to improve it I will.
Thanks!

Comment: @kosmikgirl if you look at the style guide, actually a vairantion ducks is the official recommendation: https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/
That also means that modern Redux is a variation of the ducks pattern. But it completely elimintates the need for writing action creators and action type strings, as these are autogenerated and allows to write mutable reducer logic (and wrapts that in an immutable way). It also reduces TypeScript code by a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody for your questions and suggestions. I'll definetely check the ducks documentation to improve the code once I have the time.

Regarding the solution, it was so simple:

Just adding the challenges reducer to the store.

```
const composeEnhancers = (window as any).__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  assesments: assessmentsReducer,
  auth: authReducer,
  events: eventsReducer,
  elements: elementsReducer,
  challenges: challengesReducer,
  questions: questionsReducer,
  surveys: surveysReducer,
  missions: missionsReducer,
});

export const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk)));

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
```

Thanks for taking your time to read my question

Kindly,